# HTML/CSS How to stop border from disappearing from fixed column in table when scrolling horizontally?

Tags: html, css

I have a horizontally overflowing table and I want the left most column to stick when scrolling. To do this, I gave each table cell in the left most column a class and assigned position sticky, left: 0, and z-index:25. Everything works correctly, however, the border on the right side disappears when scrolling. How can I prevent this from happening?

```
.standings-table {
  min-width: 100%;
  overflow: scroll;
  padding: 10px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.standings-table > td, th {
  padding: 0px 6px;
}

.standings-table .name-col {
  min-width: 5rem;
  position: sticky;
  background-color: inherit;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 25;
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) !important;
  padding: 4px;
}

.standings-table thead tr {
  background-color: white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) !important;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) !important;
}

tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: white;
}

tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #edeef0;
}
```

Default position
[image: default position]

After scrolling horizontally
[image]

Comment: Can you update this to a [mcve] as a runnable code snippet to demonstrate the problem?